# Azure DevOps : Create Immutable image deployment failed to find the script file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, packer

I'm looking to build Release pipeline to create a immutable ubuntu machine for my VMss.
I have deployment.sh with all required application for Vmss.

I'm trying to build Image for a Jar based application.
I have my artifacts structure as per below

[image: Artifacts folder]

I'm trying to build immutable image using build image task from azure DevOps
as given below.

[image]

On running task i'm getting a error with the following log.

```
2021-07-22T10:34:13.5841600Z ==> azure-arm: chmod: cannot access '/deployTemp/app.jar/../../deployment.sh': Not a directory
2021-07-22T10:34:13.5842952Z 
2021-07-22T10:34:13.5862730Z ==> azure-arm: /tmp/script_5507.sh: 5: /tmp/script_5507.sh: /deployTemp/app.jar/../../deployment.sh: not found
```

Any Help ?
Thanks in Advance.